# “Cmd”+“Shift”+“N” works in MacVim but not terminal VIM

Tags: vim, macvim

I use iTerm2 on Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) and I installed [YADR](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles) and that comes with all its configurations and mappings. One of the mappings maps <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to [NERDTreeToggle](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658). This however works in MacVim but not terminal VIM. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the "terminal" version and the "GUI" version likely evaluate different scripts during startup. To find the differences you can

- launch MacVim
- launch vi from the terminal
- run `:scriptnames` in both to get a list of startup scripts
- compare the two outputs

The mapping CMD+SHIFT+N is likely done in one of the scripts that are evaluated when MacVim is launched, but not when vi/vim is launched from the terminal